# Override joined-inheritance foreign key name with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I have a class CD with inherit from class Media:

CD:

```
@Entity
public class CD extends Media {
   ...
}
```

Media:

```
@Entity(name = "media")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Media extends PersistenceId<Long> {
   ...
}
```

JPA generates automatically a foreign key name and I would like to override this with the name I want:

> 03-10 18:16:58.174 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter table cd add
>   constraint FK_ehd468g2cptgh6bq6sxe75xlf foreign key (id) references
>   media (id)

How to do that ? I tried:

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverride(
   name = "id",
   foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_cd_media")
)
public class CD extends Media {
   ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "fk_cd_media"))
public class CD extends Media {
   ...
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the create table sql generated:

```
CREATE TABLE `cd` (
  `artist` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ehd468g2cptgh6bq6sxe75xlf` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `media` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I would like:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_cd_media` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `media` (`id`)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second attempt is the way to go:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "fk_cd_media"))
public class CD extends Media {
   ...
}
```

The problem is you're facing a Hibernate bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10352

Edit: The problem is solved:

> Fix Version/s: 5.0.10, 5.2.1, 5.1.1

Comment: What worked for me was `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="fk_cd_media")`

Comment: @ntholi, that is awkward, according to [documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html), the field "name" is not supposed to set the foreign key name, but the name of the primary key column, which is not the same thing.